# iMacros Add-On - Google Play

Tags: android, testing

I´m trying to record a upload of apk on google play with iMacros/Firefox.
They provide you an example for plain form:

http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Upload

It´s possible to finish process with update of apk in our play?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=ID:gwt-uid-760 CONTENT=test.apk
```